# Why my Android Studio showing different language (Chinese or Japanese) other than English?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10 I have freshly installed Android Studio. But strangely it is not showing English. I have downloaded Android Studio from https://developer.android.com/studio.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have checked my System language and also tried to search for language setting in Android Studio. I thought this may be very common issue. But not found single blog indicating any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try.

Go to
Settings > Appearance & Behaviours > Appearance and then to UNCHECK Use Custom Font and allow the built-in defaults to be applied.

I can also see the Nyan Cat Plugin installed. Go to the Plugin section and check the Plugin. Disable all plug-ins you don't need.

If everything fails. Download the zip version of android studio and open studiox86 from the bin folder after extracting. Select do not import settings on being prompted.